# Contour labels on SliceContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling

`SliceContourPlot3D` doesn't seem to come with the option of putting contour labels on the plots as far as I can see. I'm using the `"XStackedPlanes"` option. I don't see any information about how one might go about it on the web or in the documentation.

Let me explain a little further: I don't see any clear example of how to do it without a lot of manual intervention.

Example of a `SliceContourPlot3D` plot below:

```
SliceContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {"XStackedPlanes"}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

Here is how it renders without labels...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `SliceContourPlot3D` is a new function and,.perhaps, is not yet fully developed.  Certainly, it should accommodate `ContourLabels`, but it does not.

Comment: There isn't any way for `ContourPlot3D` too so I suppose it was not overlooked. And it was assumed legending is enough.